# Generating missing consecutive dates between dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file that is dynamically generated(i.e., file headers remain the same but values changes). For instance, let the file be of this form:

```
ID,CLASS,DATE,MRK
1,321,02/12/2016,30
2,321,05/12/2016,40
3,321,06/12/2016,0
4,321,07/12/2016,60
5,321,10/12/2016,70
6,876,5/12/2016,100
7,876,7/12/2016,80
```

Notice for `CLASS` `321` there are some missing dates namely `03/12/2016`, `04/12/2016`, `08/12/2016`, `09/12/2016`. I'm trying to insert the missing dates in the appropriate places with their corresponding value for `MRK` being `0`. The expected output would be like so:

```
ID,CLASS,DATE,MRK
1,321,02/12/2016,30
2,321,03/12/2016,0
3,321,04/12/2016,0
4,321,05/12/2016,40
5,321,06/12/2016,0
6,321,07/12/2016,60
7,321,08/12/2016,0
8,321,09/12/2016,0
9,321,10/12/2016,70
10,876,5/12/2016,100
11,876,6/12/2016,0
12,876,7/12/2016,80
```

This is what i came up with so far:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('In.txt')
resampled_df = df.resample('D').mean()
print resampled_df
```

But I'm getting exception:

`TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'`

Could somebody help out a python newbie here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert to datetimes and then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by `CLASS` and [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.resample.html) and last add column `ID` by [`insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html):

```
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], dayfirst=True)

df = (df.set_index('DATE')
        .groupby('CLASS')
        .resample('d')['MRK']
        .asfreq()
        .fillna(0)
        .astype(int)
        .reset_index())

df.insert(0, 'ID', range(1, len(df) + 1))
print (df)
    ID  CLASS       DATE  MRK
0    1    321 2016-12-02   30
1    2    321 2016-12-03    0
2    3    321 2016-12-04    0
3    4    321 2016-12-05   40
4    5    321 2016-12-06    0
5    6    321 2016-12-07   60
6    7    321 2016-12-08    0
7    8    321 2016-12-09    0
8    9    321 2016-12-10   70
9   10    876 2016-12-05  100
10  11    876 2016-12-06    0
11  12    876 2016-12-07   80
```

Alternative solution:

```
df = (df.set_index('DATE')
        .groupby('CLASS')
        .resample('d')['MRK']
        .first()
        .fillna(0)
        .astype(int)
        .reset_index())

df.insert(0, 'ID', range(1, len(df) + 1))
print (df)
    ID  CLASS       DATE  MRK
0    1    321 2016-12-02   30
1    2    321 2016-12-03    0
2    3    321 2016-12-04    0
3    4    321 2016-12-05   40
4    5    321 2016-12-06    0
5    6    321 2016-12-07   60
6    7    321 2016-12-08    0
7    8    321 2016-12-09    0
8    9    321 2016-12-10   70
9   10    876 2016-12-05  100
10  11    876 2016-12-06    0
11  12    876 2016-12-07   80
```

Last for same format as input use [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df['DATE'] = df['DATE'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
print (df)
    ID  CLASS        DATE  MRK
0    1    321  02/12/2016   30
1    2    321  03/12/2016    0
2    3    321  04/12/2016    0
3    4    321  05/12/2016   40
4    5    321  06/12/2016    0
5    6    321  07/12/2016   60
6    7    321  08/12/2016    0
7    8    321  09/12/2016    0
8    9    321  10/12/2016   70
9   10    876  05/12/2016  100
10  11    876  06/12/2016    0
11  12    876  07/12/2016   80
```

Comment: Hi, the solution works fine. A small concern, i noticed that the date-format has changed in the output file. Any reason why i can't keep it the same as in the input file?

Comment: For same format use `df['DATE'] = df['DATE'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')`

Answer (score 4):

Read your CSV like this -

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', 
                 sep=',', 
                 parse_dates=['DATE'],  
                 dayfirst=True,         # this is important since you have days first
                 index_col=['DATE'])
```

Now, call `groupby` + `resample` + `first`, and tie up loose ends -

```
df = df.groupby('CLASS').resample('1D')[['MRK']].first() 

df.ID = np.arange(1, len(df) + 1)
df.MRK = df.MRK.fillna(0).astype(int)

df.reset_index()

    CLASS       DATE  ID  MRK
0     321 2016-12-02   1   30
1     321 2016-12-03   2    0
2     321 2016-12-04   3    0
3     321 2016-12-05   4   40
4     321 2016-12-06   5    0
5     321 2016-12-07   6   60
6     321 2016-12-08   7    0
7     321 2016-12-09   8    0
8     321 2016-12-10   9   70
9     876 2016-12-05  10  100
10    876 2016-12-06  11    0
11    876 2016-12-07  12   80
```

In particular, `MRK` needs `fillna`. The rest can be forward filled.

---

If the order of columns is important, here's another version.

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', 
                 sep=',', 
                 parse_dates=['DATE'],  
                 dayfirst=True)

c = df.columns
df = df.set_index('DATE').groupby('CLASS').resample('1D')[['MRK']].first()

df['MRK'] = df.MRK.fillna(0).astype(int)
df['ID'] = np.arange(1, len(df) + 1)
df = df.reset_index().reindex(columns=c)
df['DATE'] = df['DATE'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

df

    ID  CLASS        DATE  MRK
0    1    321  02/12/2016   30
1    2    321  03/12/2016    0
2    3    321  04/12/2016    0
3    4    321  05/12/2016   40
4    5    321  06/12/2016    0
5    6    321  07/12/2016   60
6    7    321  08/12/2016    0
7    8    321  09/12/2016    0
8    9    321  10/12/2016   70
9   10    876  05/12/2016  100
10  11    876  06/12/2016    0
11  12    876  07/12/2016   80
```

Comment: Hi, the solution works fine. A small concern, i noticed that the date-format has changed in the output file. Any reason why i can't keep it the same as in the input file?

Comment: @Edward I don't think it matters anymore, but see my edit.